# BreakLines don't work

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I have a portion of code that is larger than page. I use following lstlisting configuration:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
columns=fullflexible,
xleftmargin=3ex,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
escapechar=`
}
```

the code is in the following place:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\HRule
\begin{lstlisting}
   MY LONG CODE
\end{lstlisting}
\HRule
\caption{some code.\label{fig:code}}
\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately the figure with code is not split between two pages,but shows only the part that fits single page.What may cause the problem and what is its solution?

Comment: `figure` is a box so prevents any page breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A floating environment cannot have a pagebreak! Use instead

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=some code.,label=fig:code]
   MY LONG CODE
\end{lstlisting}
```

If you want the caption below the code then use also `captionpos=b`.